# Lot of threads waiting for a mutex

Tags: multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

The following situation occured in some code I found. A lot (about 10) of threads use one mutex to write or read from a map. The mutex locking is done with a lock_guard. My question is about the situation where the thread number increased and 10 threads are waiting at the same time for the mutex. I know that there is no guarantee on the order. Are there any side effects on this situation? Is there at least a guarantee that every thread is able to lock the mutex or may there be threads that never get a chance to access the data structure because others are faster?

Comment: Are all threads of same priority?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685112/pthreads-thread-starvation-caused-by-quick-re-locking

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be asking about is starvation -- can a thread never get access to the mutex if it is always in contention.

`std::mutex` is not "fair".  More than that, it is not starvation-safe.  There are no forward progress guarantees for individual threads in that situation.

You can create a more complex data structures that guarantee fairness or even forward progress, but they have more overhead.

You might want to consider using a `std::shared_mutex` in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or `std::shared_timed_mutex` in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) to reduce contention, as that would permit multiple readers to clear out of the way faster.

Comment: I think I mean starvation. At the moment, there is no C++17 support for me. A simple solution for now could be using a condition variable to tell other threads that the resource is free.